# SSMS Editing cell unable to insert row - invalid uuid - how to paste a valid uuid into a cell in edit top 200 rows?

Tags: sql-server, uuid

In SSMS, trying to add some test data by editing top 200 rows. How do I get a [uuid](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) to paste into the cell? I'm trying not to have to write insert statements.

Have tried getting uuids from [an online uuid generator](https://www.uuidgenerator.net/) - tried all formats from this generator. Reviewing other stack overflow questions seem to relate to programming rather than editing issues with uuids. Tried adding uuid enclosed with single quotes and without single quotes.

[image: the error message is...]

Comment: [uniqueidentifier (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). However, why are you trying to insert a value? Normally either the table uses a default value, or it's passed by the application.

Comment: Also, I would use an `UPDATE` statement to update the value of a row, not the GUI of SSMS.

Comment: @larnu thanks for taking the time to respond. i'm inserting a value manually to  unit test the program that reads the table and the program to insert data hasn't been written yet.

Comment: @Larnu do you know why GUI of SSMS doesn't allow input of UUIDs?

Comment: I can't say I've ever tried, I don't use the GUI, I use T-SQL for my DML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unfortunately the field is defined as binary 16, not null.

AFAIK, Enterprise Manager doesn't allow pasting into binary fields.

If you define the column with the correct data type of `uniqueidentifier` your paste should work just fine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

The fix isn't to use an INSERT statement (although that is a workaround for right now), the fix is to use the correct datatype.

As an added benefit, the uniqueidentifier column won't allow invalid values, while binary will handle any bytes you can jam in there.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the willingness of the DBA to change the data type, as to whether it's a "fix" or not ;) (Just watch it turn out to be sqls2005 too)

Comment: @CaiusJard I always feel bad seeing a design decision that will make things difficult for years to come. In 2025, people will still be grumbling about the binary UUID in the database because it won't be changeable at that point. 8-)

Comment: Amen, nip these things in the bud now!

Comment: @Caius Jard  - thanks to you both for the comments and answers, it's not changeable now as binary UUID is in widespread across the system, but from what you are saying I'm taking it that best practice database design now is to use uniqueidentifier rather than binary UUID. I appreciate your feedback

Comment: One of those situations where i'd consider making another column that is a UUID, using a trigger to keep the values in sync, and gradually transitioning the code to using the UUID, then dropping the BINARY 16

Answer (score 1):

The error message says:

> You cannot use the results pane to set this field to values other than null

I would presume this means you cannot supply a guid in the grid, you have to leave it null

Does the column have a default value of NewID()? If so, it should fill in itself when you commit the row (focus another row)

If not, try inserting data by writing an INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO table(list,of,columns,except,auto,generated,ones)
VALUES ('list','of','values'...)
```

Or by selecting/modifying them from elsewhere:

```
INSERT INTO table(list,of,columns,except,auto,generated,ones)
SELECT mixed,'list','of','values',and,columns
FROM othertable
```

Comment: thank you for your time and answer, unfortunately the field is defined as binary 16, not null. There seems to be a consensus in the responses to this question that I should write an insert statement, which I will now do. I'm disappointed with SSMS edit not allowing pasting of uuids.   I'll leave this answer 'unticked' for a while just in case there is a way of editing in a uuid.

Comment: Why not choose the dedicated UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type for the column? I’m sure my SSMS 2017 can edit those

Comment: sounds interesting, I'll mention it to the DBA.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017